# Make step definition dynamic to handle any incoming text

Tags: cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I have to run `test1.feature` file against two urls. In one of the url I have got a field named as `EIN`, but in second url the same field named as `ABN`
How can we make the step definition dynamic to handle any text coming in second string.

Url 1 : https://testsite.us.com/student

The Field is named as "EIN"

Url 2: https://testsite.au.com/student

The Field is named as "ABN"

`test1.feature`

```
And I type "11 234 234 444" in "ABN" field
```

`step_definition`

//Type text value in textbox input field

```
Then('I type {string} in {string} field', (textval, textboxname) => {
  switch (textboxname) {
    case "Email":
    case "Work Phone":
    case "ABN":
    case "EIN":
    case "ACN":
      cy.get('#profile_container').parent().find('.fieldHeaderClass').contains(textboxname)
        .next().find('input')
        .clear({force:true})
        .type(textval, { force: true });
      break;
      
    //final else condition
    default:
      cy.get('#profile_container').parent().find('.fieldHeaderClass').contains(textboxname)
        .next()
        .type(textval, { force: true });

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all a great tip: Make use of page objects (POM design pattern). A page objects is an object (inside a third .js file besides your features and stepdifinitions) that you import in the stepdefinitions file that contains all of your selector code (`cy.get(......)`). You don't want selector code in your stepdefinitions. Makes it messy and more difficult to read.

Concerning your problem: If you want to repeat the same logic for (all kinds of) input values. Why not write your logic just ones (so without the long case statement) and use **Scenario Outline** to repeat your step for the different inputs? If your logic must be different every time, than don't even bother fixing this problem. Then you should simply write different steps for different logic..

Here is an example of scenario outline (inside a .feature):

```
Scenario Outline: Scenario Outline name  
    Given I type "<textval>" in "<textboxname>" field
     Examples:
      | textval            | textboxname |
      | some_value         | ABN         |
      | some_other_value   | EIN         |
      | some_other_value_2 | email       |
      | some_other_value_3 | ACN         |
      | some_other_value_4 | Work Phone  |
```

**Conclusion**: Use *Scenario Outline* to repeat logic. If logic needs to be different for different inputs, then write another stepdefinition and don't try to combine and clip different logics into 1 step.